# Android Play only 1 sound at a time

Tags: android, button, audio

I have created a soundboard and am having trouble getting just one sound to play at a time. If another button is pressed I want the current button to stop playing and the new button to begin. I also want sounds to stop when pressing the next or back button.

Is there any code that can help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some information for you that can help you solve your problem:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html
http://www.androidsnippets.com/playing-sound-fx-for-a-game

But like Falmarri pointed out, we're here to help on code and correct in need, not to write an app for you :)

Answer (score 1):

The Android docs do not tell you how to build something, they only tell you what the parts do.  Kinda like throwing parts at someone with detailed information of the parts, then expecting them to build an engine.  The real world doesn't work that way!!

Here is what you need Paul. I use this code a lot:

```
private static SoundManager SM;//Field variable to hold sound manager.

    SM = new SoundManager();  //Create sound manager
    SM.initSounds(getBaseContext());
    SM.addSound(1, R.raw.snd_loop_1);//Add sounds.  Sounds go in /res/raw
    SM.addSound(2, R.raw.snd_loop_2);
    SM.addSound(3, R.raw.snd_ok_1);
```

Then you can call the sounds on demand with  SM.playSound(1);

If you need a permanent running background loop, you can call the same sound with SM.playLoopedSound(2);

I hope it helps!

Comment: The comment you are complaining about is almost 3 months old... so I removed your rant and upvoted, I hope you do not mind.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I managed to work it in the end but by posting again because as you say pointing people to those kind of documents don't help at all.